# Tokenizing string input using a function

Tags: arrays, c, lvalue

I'm a beginner in C and I have this piece of code here, where I'm trying to tokenize a "string" input. I assume the answer is pretty obvious, but I am asking for help since I have reviewed the manual many times and simply can't find the bug. The purpose of tokenizing is to create separate process to execute basic linux commands since I'm trying to build a shell. Thank you all in advance.

```
//PROMPT is defined as "$"
void tokenizeInput(char input[]) {
    char *piece;
    int i = 0;
    int *argument;
    int pst[] = 0;
    char temp = ' ';
    piece = &temp;
    
    piece = strtok(input, PROMPT);
    while (input != NULL) {
        (*argument)[pst] = piece;
        strcat((*argument)[pst++], "\0");
        piece = strtok(NULL, PROMPT);             
        puts(piece);      
        piece = NULL;  
    } 
}
```

The error I get is `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`, at `[pst++]` which is an argument in `strcat`.

Comment: I get `main.c:11:15: error: invalid initializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your questions's title, I believe you would like some hints on using `strok`. There follows a commented example (see bellow)

Your code, however, has some other problems. Function `strtok` modifies the argument, so you would better pass it a `char*` rather than a `char[]`. Also `pst[]` an array, while `pst` itself is a constant-pointer (to the first block of memory where your array is allocated). You can't increment `pst`. I guess you need an inter index for it. Or, perhaps, depending on the logic you have in mind, you want to increment `pst[0]`, instead.

Do not hesitate to ask more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[1024], *p;

  /* This is an example of a line we ant to parse. */
  strcpy (buffer, "Hello Token World");

  printf ("Buffer is: %s\n", buffer);

  /* The function strtok process the string in 'buffer' and finds the first 
     ocurrency of any of the characters present in the string 'delimiters'
     
     p = strtok (char *buffer, char *deliminters)

     The function puts a string-end mark ('\0') where it found the delimiter
     and returns a pointer to the bining of the buffer.
*/

  /* Finds the first white space in buffer. */
  p = strtok (buffer, " ");

  /* Now, go on searching for the next delimiters. 

     p = strtok (NULL, char *delimiters)

     The function "remembers" the place where it found the delimiter.
     If the furst argument is NULL, the function starts searching
     from this position instead of the start of buffer. Therefore
     it will find the first delimiter starting from where it ended
     the last time, and will return a pointer to the first 
     non-delimiter after this point (that it, the next token).
*/

  while (p != NULL)
    {
      printf ("Token: %s\n", p);
      p = strtok (NULL, " ");   /* Find the next token. */
    }

  /* Notice that strtok destroys 'buffer' by adding '\0' to every
     ocurrency of a delimiter.*/

  printf ("Now buffer is: %s\n", buffer);

  /* See 'man strtok' or the libc manual for furter information. */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, useful to post sample output of the code.

Comment: fjm ,  I appreciate your willingness and your complete answer , but a version of the code where  the input  is dynamically allocated would be more corresponding to my needs. I hope you will come up with an equally good answer .

Comment: @georgiostsobys, you mean  `strtok (buffer, " ")` with `buffer` being dynamically allocated? In this case, just change `char buffer[1024]` with `char *buffer; buffer=malloc(1024)`.  Actually, you would better do `buffer=malloc(1024*sizeof(char))` and test if `buffer != NULL` to make sure the allocation was successful.  Do not hesitate to ask again if this does not solve your question.